# Intercepting Android Methods

Tags: android

Is their any way to intercept any existing methods of android and rewrite our implementation to it ?

I have found some techniques like method swizzling in iOS which helps us to do us can we do the same in android .

Can we have generalized technique to intercept a certain function of all the applications installed on a android phone.
e.g. I want to intercept onCreate Method of all the android applications present on my android phone.

Comment: Well, lot of companies are involved in doing the projects, its certainly not a flawed approach, I have completed a similar approach on iOS platform.There are several corporate demands for which such approaches are to be used.

Comment: Using rootkit methods for all apps doesn't seems to be a good approach. If you trying to add additional security you should tackle it at system and not app level. Doing something else like injecting ads, tracker or something similar is an assault at the users rights - corporate demands or not. How is that not flawed?

Comment: We do this at framework level, this is done something before installing the apps, this apps are not those you get on the googleplay, this are apps on the private servers of somecompanies, and access is only certain people, which have agreed to use the apps

Comment: Again: that's a conceptual flaw. Why attack the system integrity if you're (or other partners) in charge of the apps? But as I can see Chris Stratton comment convinced you to go a more clean and less intrusive way. That's great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easiest to do this if you can either:

A) modify the installation of Android itself, changing the behavior of the runtime

B) modify particular apk's of interest before installation, replacing the symbolic names in the smali code with your alternatives.

For those calls which involve Binder IPC (most things of interest do, but perhaps not at the level where they are most easily interpreted, and usually not at a level considered *portable* across versions), another option might be to intercept that traffic, either with a modified Binder driver in the kernel, by pointing /dev/binder at a proxy, or at the level of C library open/ioctl/etc calls using something like an LD_PRELOAD when starting zygote or otherwise modifying the C library.

You might also be able to do something by modifying dalvik (though beware of the dex optimization process resolving symbolic name at install time rather than run time - so perhaps do the substitutions during odexing).

Another possibility would be debugging the application, at either jdwp or native level, and thus trapping whatever is interesting.

Finally, it may be possible to run an app in a virtual execution environment, where you have the chance to proxy all interactions with the actual hosting Android system.

From a security perspective, all of these methods require either an exception to the usual Android security model (root, system install ability, or security bug), cooperation of the user (modifying apk before installation, or installing it in virtual environment rather than directly), or cooperation of the app developer (leaving debug flag on, building the interception into your own app)

Comment: Ya, this is what I am trying to achieve, do you have any reference for this. Or how to do this.

Comment: I liked your approach, of working on native level rather than forking and changing the OS itself

Comment: Do we need to create wrapper for the applications so that i can a wrapper for the apk before installing and the wrapper would serve the purpose of exchanging the implementations of the existing code with the my implementations for those functions ?

Comment: It would be easier to create scripts to automatically patch the apk's of interest, adding your own precompiled interception handling code and replacing the names of methods (both defined and invoked) with those of your interceptors.  So for example, you rename their onCreate() to onCreateReal(), and add your own onCreate() that eventually calls theirs.  Or you add your own subclass of Activity, change theirs to extend yours rather than the platform's, and use the fact that onCreate() has to invoke it's superclass method.

Comment: great,I will be adding a lot of comments while doing this !! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to intercept onCreate Method of all the android applications present on my android phone.

Fortunately, this is not possible, for blindingly obvious security reasons, except *maybe* if you root your phone and replace the Android framework JAR with one that adds in your desired security flaws.

Comment: There is something called "Platform Libraries", its a provision to add our implementation to the code, although its a security breach, but companies do use it for their own implementation , something adding their own corporate security policies too. Now, that is for some methods of android. onCreate is type of internal function , kind of delegate function for Activity. I want to intercept that method.

Comment: @NileshAgrawal: "There is something called "Platform Libraries"" -- that is part of making your own custom device or ROM mod. "I want to intercept that method" -- the good news is that you can't, without rooting or modding the device (or app) in question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do with without forking AOSP and changing the OS.

Comment: That's not actually true, though that is by far the cleanest method.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with a combination [Magisk](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/releases) and then writing a [Xposed module](https://github.com/ElderDrivers/EdXposed). Write a Android app using the [API](https://api.xposed.info/reference/packages.html) and then enable it as an module in the Xposed manager.

**NOTE:** Obviously this requires a rooted device. It will never be allowed to play around with other applications and packages in the wild on unrooted phones.